# Formula $\text{deg}f^*D=\text{deg}f\cdot\text{deg}D$ and $n=\sum_i e_i f_i$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In proposition  II.6.9 page 138 Hartshorne write $\text{deg}f^*D=\text{deg}f\cdot\text{deg}D$ for $X,Y$ non singular curves  (over an algebraically closed field $k$) and $f:X\to Y$ a finite morphism. When I see this formula I think to decomposition in number field with $f:\text{Spec}(A)\to\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$ induced by inclusion hence with $D=\mathfrak{p}=(p)$ the equality $\mathfrak{p}A=\prod_i \mathfrak{q}_i^{e_i}$ becomes $f^*(\mathfrak{p})=\sum_i e_i \mathfrak{q}_i$. I guess there is a generalization of formula II.6.9 that should take into account of the dimensions $[k(\mathfrak{q}_i):k(\mathfrak{p})]=f_i$ and generalize $n=\sum_i e_i f_i$. Do you know this generalization and in what standard refenrence it is studied? Thanks

Comment: To unify the number fields and the curves, for a finite extension $L/K$ you can look at how a discrete valuation $v$ on $K$ extends to $L$ ($R$ the integral closure of $o_v$ in $L$, $\pi_v R = \prod_j (\varpi_j)^{e_j}$, $O_j = (R-(\varpi_j))^{-1} R, v_j(a) = \sup \{ m, \pi_v \in \varpi_j^m O_j\}$, $\pi_v O_j = (\varpi_j)^{e_j}$, $e_j = v_j(\pi_v)$, $f_j = [O_j/(\varpi_j):o_v/(\pi_v)], [L:K]= \sum_j e_j f_j$)

Comment: @reuns Thanks again! Do you have any reference/key word for such generalzation?

Comment: I found in Liu (7.3.1 page 275) a generalization of the definition of degree when the based field is not algebraically closed: $\text{deg}(\sum_i n_i P_i)=\sum_i n_i [k(P_i):k]$. One uses here that the curve is a variety to know that $[k(P_i):k]$ is finite hence this generalization is not sufficient for number theory.

Comment: Yes there is, you can consider any finite extension of Dedekind domains $B/A$ and the corresponding map $f: Spec(B) \to Spec(A)$. See Lecture $6$ of MIT Number Theory $1$ course by Andrew Sutherland given in Fall $2017$ (https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-785-number-theory-i-fall-2017/lecture-notes/MIT18_785F17_lec6.pdf)